# How to display multiple rows of data from database in ReportViwer using C# RDLC

Tags: c#

I am a new user of RDLC and ReportViewer, I want to show a multi row query result in `ReportViwer` using C# and a `.RDLC` report.

The parameter is passed to `TableAdapter` from a textbox. It is to be mention here that my query in Query Builder returns the required data, but my following code shows only the first row of the result in all rows.

```
 private void txtSID_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {  
        string sid = "";
        int isid = 0;
        sid = txtSID.Text.ToString();

        if (int.TryParse(sid, out isid)) ; 

        this.CustomerTableAdapter.Fill(this.CustomerInsttDataSet.Customer, isid);
        this.installmentPaymentHistoryTableAdapter.Fill(this.insttDataGridData.InstallmentPaymentHistory, isid);

        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
}
```

Please tell me what i am missing to show all rows of my query in ReportViewer.
I think I am missing `GetData()` method but I could not find exact way to use this method. Please let me now the code to resolve it